# something wrong with my model with differetial controller

Tags: ros, gazebo, rviz

[image]

i did not find out where the problem lied in.i tried to control my robot in gazebo,failed.Then i used rviz to see the topic,finding the problem shown in image below.
my yaml :controller_joint_names: ['', 'RB_wheel', 'RF_wheel', 'LF_wheel', 'LB_wheel', ]
my urdf tag:    
transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission

hardware_interface/VelocityJointInterface


hardware_interface/VelocityJointInterface
1

```
  <transmission name="front_right_joint_trans">
        <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
        <joint name="RF_wheel" >
            <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/VelocityJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
        </joint>
        <actuator name="front_right_joint_motor">
            <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/VelocityJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
            <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
        </actuator>
    </transmission>
```

Debug
                true
                /
              world 
                1
                true

```
            <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
            <updateRate>100.0</updateRate>
            <legacyMode>true</legacyMode>
            <leftJoint>LF_wheel</leftJoint>
            <rightJoint>RF_wheel</rightJoint>
            <wheelSeparation>2.3</wheelSeparation>
            <wheelDiameter>1.2358</wheelDiameter>
            <broadcastTF>1</broadcastTF>
            <wheelTorque>30</wheelTorque>
            <wheelAcceleration>1.8</wheelAcceleration>
            <commandTopic>cmd_vel</commandTopic>
            <odometryFrame>odom</odometryFrame> 
            <odometryTopic>odom</odometryTopic> 
            <robotBaseFrame>base_footprint</robotBaseFrame>
        </plugin>
```

i could not find the reason why i cannot control my robot,can anyone help me

Comment: please correct the sentence formatting in your post ... add a space after every comma and after every period ... right now, it is messy and difficult to read

Comment: thank you for your suggestions, I use this web for the first time,confused about how to correct the formation.I will learn to change the way I ask

Comment: What is the contents of the joint_state topic and who's providing that?

Comment: I thought differential_drive_controller plugin provides the topic.I just browse
 the plugin again,it does not contain joint_state topic.The way I seek bugs was wrong!Thank you for helping me.